# Can we use Present continuous to describe routine?

Tags: present-continuous

I write an essay about effects of pandemic on people's life. I want to describe remote work or learning online. Should I write:

1.During this pandemic some people **works** from home.

2.During this pandemic some people **are working** from home.

the same with:

1.Students **learn** online.

2.Students **are learning** online.

When I checked in google, there are more results with Present Continuous tense, but I can't understand why. It's not something that happens now, in this exact moment but it's just a fact that they work/learn like that because of this whole pandemic situation.

Comment: [some people (plural noun) work at home.] [I'm writing an essay].

Answer (score 2):

The present continuous can be used to describe a **temporary habit**. Compare:

- I **work** in an office but these days I **'m working** from home.
- We always **eat** in the dining room but now it's being painted so we **'re eating** in the kitchen.
- I **sleep** in my bedroom but my cousins have come over so I **'m sleeping** in the living room.